# How to assign CRS to RasterLayer in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a layer with `coord. ref. : NA`.

How can I assign `coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0` to `coord. ref. : NA`?

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 127, 146, 18542  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -122.39, -120.93, 36.72, 37.99  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : C:\2012Tif\2012ASC5min_ppt_spas1306_0001_20121222_0005_UTC.asc.tif 
names       : X2012ASC5min_ppt_spas1306_0001_20121222_0005_UTC.asc 
values      : 0, 0.0782172  (min, max)


class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 180, 240, 43200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -123.305, -120.905, 36.705, 38.505  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +to wgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\nahmlee\Documents\1998Test.tif 
names       : X1998Test 
values      : 0, 0.07884484  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `crs` function. If `r` is your raster:

```
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Of course, you need to be sure it is the correct projection for your raster.

Comment: The result is the same, but this version is easier adaptable to other reference systems: `crs(r) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:4326')` if you know the EPSG number.

Comment: This should be `CRS("+init=epsg:28992")` for `rgdal`.

Comment: The correct and full syntax shouldt be 'proj4string(r) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5678")'

Comment: Note that PROJ4 is on its way out. The PROJ6 way would be `raster::crs(r) <- "EPSG:4326"`