# writeRaster() not preserving EPSG information

Tags: raster, r, epsg

I need to upload some rasters in .tif format to a geoserver that requires EPSG information to correctly display the data.  When I assign an EPSG using `crs()` to a raster that is in memory, the WKT information reflects that EPSG code correctly.  However, when I write that raster to disk and read it back into R to double check, the EPSG code is not preserved and the WKT information is different (though the crs is the same).

```r
memoryCRS <- raster("wiltpoint.tif")
crs(memoryCRS) <- "EPSG:5070"
writeRaster(memoryCRS, "wiltpoint2.tif")
diskCRS <- raster("wiltpoint2.tif")

cat(wkt(memoryCRS))
#> PROJCRS["NAD83 / Conus Albers",
#>    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
#>        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",

cat(wkt(diskCRS))
#> PROJCRS["unknown",
#>     BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
#>         DATUM["North American Datum 1983",

all.equal(wkt(memoryCRS), wkt(diskCRS))
#> [1] "1 string mismatch"

identicalCRS(memoryCRS, diskCRS)
#> [1] TRUE

compareCRS(memoryCRS, diskCRS)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Have you tried the proj4string rather than the EPSG code?

Comment: Try `crs(memoryCRS) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5070")`, see comments here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111227/14229"

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried ``` crs(memoryCRS) <- CRS('+init=epsg:5070') ``` and it has the same issue.  Same goes for ``` proj4string(memoryCRS) <- '+init=epsg:5070' ``` and ``` projection(memoryCRS) <- '+init=epsg:5070' ```

Comment: I would like to better understand this problem. Why must the server have EPSG code? (that would be odd, as  there is an infinite number of coordinate reference systems; and a finite number of EPSG codes); and how should it be stored?

Comment: My understanding is that the GeoServer can't register a layer without a clearly identifiable EPSG code and matching WKT and that the same proj string can correspond to more than one EPSG codes.  In the example above, the difference in that first line: PROJCRS["NAD83 / Conus Albers", and PROJCRS["unknown", is why the GeoServer is not correctly recognizing the raster.

Answer (score 1):

Try using capitals for epsg: `crs(memoryCRS) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:5070")` instead of `crs(memoryCRS) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5070")`